# Edit a config variable of a custom module in controller in Drupal 8

Tags: controller, drupal-8

Is it possible to edit/create a config variable of a module in a controller created in the same module?

For example:
module_name/src/Controller/MyController.php:

```
class MyController extends ControllerBase {

    public function x($y) {
        $config = \Drupal::config('module_name.settings');
        $config->set('var1', $y)->save();
    }
}
```

module_name.module:

```
function module_name_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('module_name.settings');
  var_dump($config->get('var1'));
}
```

module_name/config/install/module_name.settings.yml:

```
var1: 0
```

module_name/src/Form/moduleNameSettings.php:

```
class moduleNameSettings extends ConfigFormBase {

    protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
        return [
            'module_name.settings',
        ];
    }


    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
        $config = \Drupal::config('module_name.settings');

        $this->config('module_name.settings')
            ->set('var1', $config->get('var1'))
            ->save();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To update the configuration variable's value use below code :

```
$config_factory = \Drupal::configFactory();
$config = $config_factory->getEditable('module_name.settings'); //Fetch the drupal configuration settings
$config->set('foo', '1');
$config->save(TRUE);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Vernit! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your solution to include an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem :)

Comment: Thanks Joel! Code is self-explanatory ... Load the configuration and set the new value for update.